# awk print variables with number of fields together

Tags: awk

I have a bunch of files, and I would like to see how many columns a file has for all of the files with a certain name. So after reading around in the forum, I wrote the code below, but it doesn't print out the file name. Could somebody kindly point out the problem for me please? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
for file in $(find ./ -name "*_intersect.txt")
do 
name=$(basename $file) 
awk -v var="$name" '{print name,NF; exit}' $file
done
```

the expected output could be

```
file1 4
file2 8
file3 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `print name` to `print var`.

`name` is a shell variable. `var` is the awk variable you're populating with the contents of `name` when you do `-v var="$name"`. Inside awk you have access to awk variables, not shell variables. See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).